# Control.BeginInvoke execution order from single thread

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a very simple question regarding the [`Control.BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx)-method present on Windows Forms-controls. Are the delegates being passed into this method always executed in the same order in which they are inserted?

*Example:*

```
// Can I safely assume that the assignment of "3" to 
// 'label1.Text' will allways be last?
BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { label1.Text = "1"; });
BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { label1.Text = "2"; });
BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { label1.Text = "3"; });
```

Please note that I don't have to worry about multiple threads calling 'BeginInvoke', which is a scenario that is being treated with this question: [Control.BeginInvoke Execution Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952711/control-begininvoke-execution-order). I'm merely concerned with if there is any guarantee of execution order when the 'BeginInvoke'-invocations originate from a single thread.

**If anyone can point me to an official source confirming this behaviour I'd be happy to receive it.** Right now I have nothing but this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/4f6d7b0f-8b43-44db-bc27-eea13303cc40/controlbegininvoke-multiple-times-execution-order?forum=winforms, in which the following statement is made:

> Control.BeginInvoke uses the window message loop and a queue behind the scenes. The delegates are enqueued on the thread that calls BeginInvoke, but the message inserted into the loop blindly dequeues the next delegate from the queue and invokes it on the UI thread.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I believe the behavior is undefined. It may be consistent within a .NET framework version but a random windows update may be allowed to change it's behavior (I think, that is why I am posting  a comment instead of a answer)

Comment: There is a hidden lock built into Control.BeginInvoke() that serializes access to the invoke queue. Necessary to keep the queue thread-safe. As long as the BeginInvokes execute on the same thread then you have a rockhard guarantee that they always execute in order. If multiple threads do it then it is merely safe and there is no order guarantee unless you add synchronization yourself.